# How do I safely dispose of my LiPo batteries?

Tags: lipo-batteries

I have an old LiPo battery that is nearing the end of its life, how can I dispose of it safely?

Comment: This question is not related to drones. Perhaps it belongs on SE.Electronics?

Comment: @KennSebesta Pretty confident it belongs here, as one of the example questions for this site

Comment: @Danil, could you point to where? In the commitment phase, https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29920/how-does-the-topic-of-this-site-differ-from-aviation-electric-engineering-and-r was asked and at that stage it was crucial to show how we'd be different from EE and ME questions. I feel this kind of open-ended question about a tech we just happen to use, but is not otherwise important to our field, is not in our domain.

Comment: This is a very drone-relevant question, as is evident by the huge number of articles and videos devoted to the topic of disposing of LiPo batteries in drone-related blogs/channels (and the relative scarcity of information on the same topic in non-drone-related sources).

Comment: @FlashCactus I agree with the importance, but the question I always like to ask is "how is this relevant to drones"? Disposal of hazardous waste does not change if the application was a drone or a UPS battery. If this question is already answered repeatedly, what do we think we can add to it so that this question/answer is uniquely valuable?

Comment: In no other application, by far, are lipo batteries as widespread a __consumer item__ as in RC aircraft, and as such almost nowhere else do civilians _need_ to know this. In all the other fields, they are usually disposed of by specialists dedicated to the task.

As for the second part, the value of having a common question answered on SE is to have all the relevant information (such as all possible methods of disposing of a battery, in this case) collected in one place, with anyone possessing additional knowledge being able to add to it by posting their own answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First is to discharge the battery to zero volts which can be done by using a [LiPo charger or a light bulb](https://oscarliang.com/dispose-lipo-battery-safely/). It can then be thrown into a recycle bin, but check with your municipality before doing so as some will not take them. There may be a local or regional centre where they can be dropped off.

It is not advised to use salt water as it takes a long time and its corrosive nature to metals can lead to incomplete discharge.

Comment: Check with your municipality before throwing the batteries into the recycle bin. Some will not take them. There may be a local or regional center where they can be dropped off. Don’t take disposal of LiPos lightly. It’s just a battery to  us, but it could be dangerous in a building or vehicle filled with flammable material where the employees are not aware of what they are handling.

Comment: Thanks, added @Schome1

Comment: If you are sufficiently environmentally-minded, it's better to hand the batteries to a special battery-disposal facility; the chemicals involved in the manufacture of batteries are rather toxic and very slow to degrade to a more friendly form.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, battery retailers and distributors are required to accept waste batteries for disposal if they sell more than 32kg of batteries a year (see https://www.gov.uk/battery-waste-supplier-reponsibilities.)

It is also likely that your local municipal dump will accept batteries for disposal, but you will need to check for your area.